# В переменную записываются не все цифры после перебора массива

Tags: javascript

У меня есть пустая переменная test и есть массив testArr со значениями 1,2,3.
Я перебираю массив testArr и после перебора перезаписываю пустую переменную test,
внутри перебора map console.log выводит все правильно, то есть все значения 1 2 3 но после того как я выхожу за пределы перебора то console.log выводит только 3, что делать?

```
let test;
   const testArr = [1,2,3];
   testArr.map(item => {
       test = item;
      console.log(test) // 1 2 3
   });
    console.log(test) // 3
```

Comment: test = item; вы перезаписывает переменную при каждой итерации. Вот вам и результат выводит с последней . что вы хотите записать в переменную test? чтобы она была 123?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как перезаписать переменную, но уже с нужными мне значениями?

Comment: "что делать", "что делать" - внятно формулировать желаемый результат, вот что делать.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let test;
const testArr = [1,2,3];
test = testArr.map(item => {
    console.log(item) // 1 2 3
    // тут должно быть условие для возврата item
    // и если оно true, то возвращать item
    return item;  
});
console.log(test);
```

см. пример для `map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

---

> как перезаписать переменную, но уже с нужными мне значениями?

Но скорее всего вам нужен не `map`, а `filter` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

---

> как сделать так чтобы выводилось 1 2 3 на примере?

Для этого вообще `map` не нужен, а нужен `join` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```js
let testStr = '';
const testArr = [1,2,3];
testStr = testArr.join(' ');

console.log(testStr);
```

Comment: Алексей, на выходе получаю массив со значениями [1,2,3], подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы выводилось 1 2 3 на примере?

Comment: @ОвовОчоы добавил в конец

Comment: Извинюсь не правильно сформулировал вопрос, нужно получить не одной строкой 1 2 3, а  1 следующий лог 2 следующий лог 3, надеюсь сейчас понятно объснил))

Comment: @ОвовОчоы а причём тут тогда другая переменная? ну добавьте в join другой разделитель вместо пробела

Comment: У Вас происходит разговор немого с глухим.